# Print Image from drawable folder to Bluetooth Printer - Android

Tags: android, image, printing, bluetooth

I am attempting to print a JPEG image to a Zebra bluetooth printer using an Output Stream.

I have got text working ok, but cannot print an image. I have included the code I have attempted below.

EDIT: I have now created a byte array, so I just need to know how to print a byte array to an output stream.

```
        btoutputstream = btsocket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] printformat = {0x1B, 0x21, FONT_TYPE};
        btoutputstream.write(printformat);

        String t_line1 = "! 0 100 100 185 1\r\n";
        String t_line2 = "PCX 80 30\r\n";
        String t_line3 = "PRINT\r\n";

        try {
            Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.image);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();

            btoutputstream.write(t_line1.getBytes());
            btoutputstream.write(t_line2.getBytes());

            btoutputstream.write(bitmapdata);
            btoutputstream.write(t_line3.getBytes());
        }catch(Exception e) {

        }
        btoutputstream.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print Bitmap with this: [PrintPic](https://github.com/yefengjie/BtPrinter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yefeng/night/btprinter/print/PrintPic.java)

```
try {
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.image);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintPic printPic = PrintPic.getInstance();
    printPic.init(bitmap);
    byte[] bitmapdata = printPic.printDraw();

    btoutputstream.write(t_line1.getBytes());
    btoutputstream.write(t_line2.getBytes());
    btoutputstream.write(bitmapdata);
    btoutputstream.write(t_line3.getBytes());
} catch (Exception e) {
}
btoutputstream.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

To print an image, use  [PrintHelper](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos.html#image). If you need both text and image as a document, use [PrintManager](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html).